# Match node with specific Ancestor Xpath Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So my question will seems fairly simple to any XSLT/XPATH veteran but I didn't found any post about it so here it is.

What is the correct XPATH syntax to select nodes with specific ancestor ?

Let say I want all "country" nodes that have "europe" as ancestor (not direct parent), I've tried many different syntaxes but can't find the right one neither the ressources to help me resolve this.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `//europe//country`

Answer (score 2):

`match="europe//country"` will match `country` elements with a `europe` ancestor.

Comment: wow pretty simple, I thought I had to use the ancestor axe but I guess this is only when you want to match the ancestors. Thanks !

Comment: You can use `//country[ancestor::europe]` if it tickles your fancy.